# No module named base

Tags: scikit-learn, installation, confusion-matrix

So I am trying to run..

```
import sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
```

so hey, lets reinstall everything fresh because nothing else seems to work.

```
Blakes-MacBook-Pro:P3 bmc$ sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
sudo: apt-get: command not found
Blakes-MacBook-Pro:P3 bmc$ sudo pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn
The directory '/Users/bmc/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/bmc/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Nice, so we're all up to date. Great. Lets run it.

```
Blakes-MacBook-Pro:P3 bmc$ python P3.py iris-shuffled.txt iris-shuffled.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P3.py", line 26, in <module>
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>

ImportError: No module named base
```

I have no idea what `base` is or how to get it, and if it is not in my sklearn fresh reinstall, what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have a mess of different python installations: pip is talking about `/Library/Python/2.7` and python seems to run from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`. Also, note that you did not install anything freshly. `apt-get` failed and pip did nothing - try to uninstall the packages first.

Comment: That helps. Thank you.